# Css files not updating like other files

Tags: css, hosting, web-hosting, remote-server

i am currently hosting my site on justhost (just as a test server), when i save my work on my local computer through aptana the files are automatically uploaded to the hosting server, and they appear fine. However this only works for my actual files like .php and .html

They do not work for my .css files, so if i save them and upload them the changes do not take effect, until like the next day, or if i turn my computer on and off and leave it a couple of hours, i am not sure why they are not taking effect immediately like the rest of the fiels.

I have tried deleting my cache and adding ?ver=1.0 to the end of the file name, but still no luck.

Also, i checked the hosting directly and the css file has updated to the correct version, but just does not show in browser.

Any ideas on what could be wrong, it would make life much easier if i could get them updating like the other files.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't be sure what is causing this, but if I'm correct - the files do upload, its not a case of not uploading. It's one of these things

- The Cache is holding it (already cleared it though?)
- The file is doing some odd cross server transfer, depends what sort of hosting your on, but it may be the file is getting held up somewhere
- Try clearing the DNS Cache
  Start > type CMD > in the dialog type:

  ipconfig /flushdns
- That may force the computer to reload the file.

As for an ongoing solution to prevent it in the future I'm out...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, i just figured it out, the hosting i am using uses cloudflare, so i had to edit the cloudflare to maintenance mode to automatically purge the cache, which works great now.

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a while, but as others may find this question the way I did, the solution for me was to enable Cloudflare Developer Mode. Cloudflare was keeping the css files in cache and it drove me crazy to find the solution in another forum. I hope your case may be the same as mine as thus you can solve it as well.